# Dimension of a quotient ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, krull-dimension

> What is the Krull dimension of $B=A[x,y,z]/\langle xy + 1, z + 1\rangle$, given $A$ is a Noetherian commutative ring?

Comment: I feel that you have some misconceptions. First, why would you write $B$ as $A[x,y,z]/(xy+1,z)$ and not just as $A[x,y]/(xy+1)$? For the second, are you asking whether say $\dim A[x]/(x^2+1)=\dim k[x]/(x^2+1)$ for arbitrary ring $A$ and arbitrary field $k$?

Comment: I can write $B$ as $A[x,y]/\langle xy + 1\rangle$. And I was wrong when i said its the same as fields. I will edit right away. What I meant was $\mathrm{dim}(A) + \mathrm{dim}(\Bbbk[x_1, \ldots, x_n]/\mathfrak{a})$.

Comment: For your 2nd question to make sense, you need the ideal to be generated by polynomials with coefficients in $k$ or something — otherwise the quotient $k[x_1,\dots]/a$ does  not make sense. Also, 'leading coefficient' does not generally make sense for polynomials in several variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first ring $B$ is just $A[x^{\pm1}]$, the ring of Laurent polynomials with coefficients in $A$,  which is the localization of $A[x]$ at the powers of $x$. It follows from this that $\dim B\leq\dim A[x]=\dim A+1$.

On the other hand, if $\def\p{\mathfrak p}\p$ is a prime in $A$ then $\mathfrak pB$ is a prime of $B$, easily seen to be the set of Laurent polynomials with coefficients in $\p$. If $\p_0\subsetneq\cdots\subsetneq\p_r$ is a chain of prime ideals in $A$, then $\p_0B\subsetneq\cdots\subsetneq\p_rB\subsetneq \p_rB+(x-1)B$ is a chain of prime ideals of $B$ one prime longer.

Conclusion: $\dim A[x^{\pm1}]=\dim A+1$.

Comment: how did we get that B is the localization of $A[x]$ at the powers of $x$?

Comment: The relation $xy+1=0$ means precisely that $-y$ is the inverse of $x$.

Comment: @Zoey google for "krull dimension of tensor product of algebras"

Comment: What if the ideal, $\mathfrak{a} = \langle x^2 y + x + 1, y^3 + 2z + 1 \rangle \subseteq A[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$. Should I post this as a different question?

Comment: A especial case of computing the dimensión of rings like the ones you are looking at is computinf that of tensor products.

Comment: Google more, for papers and such. There's a masters thesis on the subject, for example.