# Dimension of quotient ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

> What is the dimension of the following quotient ring, $\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]/\langle xy+2, z+4 \rangle$, where $\mathbb{Z}$ is the ring of integers?

I realized this is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[x,-2/x]$. How does $-2/x$ affect the dimension since the ring is $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: My apologies if this question sounds repetitive but I am asking only because I am trying to understand an important concept and this example will help me a lot.

Comment: Can someone  give me a hint on how to work at the solution before putting it on hold?

Comment: @Zoey Have you tried to use similar arguments to the ones from [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1386231/121097) to [another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1386106/dimension-of-a-quotient-ring) posted by you?

Comment: @user26857 here I thought $2,4$ will create problems. We have $\mathbb{Z}[x,-2/x,-4]$. Therefore dimension is 2?

Comment: Well, $-4\in\mathbb Z$, so you can remove it, right?

Comment: Thank you! You have been of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R=\mathbb Z[X,Y]/(XY+2)$. We have $\dim R\le2$. Furthermore, since $x$ is a non-zero divisor on $R$ we have $\dim R\ge\dim R/(x)+1=2$. (Note that $R/(x)\simeq(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)[Y]$.)

Comment: Why should $\mathrm{dim} R \leq 2$ ? Also how are these rings related tensor product of $A$- algebras?

Comment: @Zoey If $a\in A$ is a non-zero divisor, then $\dim A/(a)\le\dim A-1$. (In our case note that $\dim\mathbb Z[X,Y]=3$.) I've never claimed that such rings are related to the tensor product of algebras.