# Show that $k[x,x^{-1}]$ is a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

i want to show that $k[x,x^{-1}]$ (where $k$ is a field ) is a PID . i have some proof but seems too- straight forward to be correct
take the natural homomorphism $\phi: K[x]\to S^{-1}K[x]$ where  $S=(x^1,x^2...)$
for we know that for every ideal of $S^{-1}K(x)$ Lets say $I$ , $\phi^{-1}(I)$ is an ideal of $K[x]$ Which is PID
so $\phi^{-1}(I)=(f)$ for some $f$ on $K[x]$ then is holds that the ideal $I$ is generated by $(f/1)$ ? if yes we've shown that $k[x,x^{-1}]$ is a PID?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE, I edited your post so that it uses MathJax. See here if you need some references : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: In general, any localization of a PID is itself a PID.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang yes ive read that online but i was not quite sure about the proof i gave above

Comment: It follows also from [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4074364/laurent-polynomial-ring-which-is-a-pid/4074386#4074386).